# Enforcing static class constants as a data type

Tags: c#, class

I have a static class with constants. I am looking for options to create a method which takes a dictionary as an argument and enforcing the key to be one of the constants from the static class.Here is my static class with constants.
[image]

Here is what I am trying to do
[image]

And here is what I am trying to enforce
[image]

Comment: SOrry, your explanation is not clear.

Comment: I agree with @TomTom, it's confusing what you are trying to accomplish based off of the information provided.

Comment: You can only do this using reflection.

Comment: Just edited my question. Hope that will help. I am trying to force passing the constant as a key instead of just any string.

Comment: Side note: Please avoid images of code in posts and use text (formatted as code by adding  4 spaces)...

Comment: Sure. Will keep that in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though this has been already answered, there is another approach, like so:

```
public class MyOwnEnum
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    private MyOwnEnum(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static readonly MyOwnEnum FirstName = new MyOwnEnum("Firstname");
    public static readonly MyOwnEnum LastName = new MyOwnEnum("LastName");
}
```

It behaves same way like Enum and can be used in your code with same syntax. I cannot give credit to whoever came up with it, but I believe I came upon it when searching for Enums with multiple values.

Answer (score 3):

From the sound of it, an [Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) would be more suited to what you're trying to do.

```
public enum MyConstants
{
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Title
}

public void CreateMe(Dictionary<MyConstants, string> propertyBag)
{
    ...
}
```

**UPDATED**

You could combine this with attributes to associate each enum with a specific string like so:

```
public enum PropertyNames
{
    [Description("first_name")]
    FirstName,
    [Description("last_name")]
    LastName,
    [Description("title")]
    Title
}
```

The value of each description attribute associated with each enum value could easily be grabbed via an extension method, like so:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
            false);

        if (attributes != null &&
            attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then in your "CreateMe"-method you can get the description and value of each dictionary entry by doing something similar to this:

```
void CreateMe(Dictionary<PropertyNames, string> propertyBag)
{
    foreach (var propertyPair in propertyBag)
    {
        string propertyName = propertyPair.Key.GetDescription();
        string propertyValue = propertyPair.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Enums don't enforce that value of variable is actually an enum value, they are merely fancy integer constants. To check if value is actually defined in enum use `Enum.IsDefined(...)` method.

Comment: Here is the catch, the name of the constant is not the same as the value. Unlike my example. I need to pass in "first_name" in the dictionary but the user should be able to use the constant MyConstants.FirstName. Basically. My constant name will be different from its value. Which is why enums will not help. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Shazi, I've updated my initial question with the screen shot of how my constants would actually look like

Comment: You could define an custom attribute with the needed name and use that if needed

Comment: @Rishab I Think I understand what you mean. Perhaps using an enum in combination with an attribute could be a solution? I'll update my answer with an example shortly...

Comment: @Rishab Updated my answer

Comment: @Shazi Thank you very much. That will help

Answer (score 0):

With strings you can't enforce fact that keys come from limited set of vialues compile time.

Use enum or custom class (possibly with implicit conversion to string) instead.